# Sticky nav in rails app scrolling to far down

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, footer

This code seems to be pushing my footer too far down that it results to having to scroll, even though there is no content as such. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my application.html.erb code

```
 <body>
 <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

 <div id="wrap">
     <div class="container">
     <%= yield %>
     </div>
     <div id="push"></div>  
 </div>

 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
 </body>
```

Here is the _footer partial code

```
<footer>
    <%= link_to "Blog", "#" %>
    <%= link_to "Twitter", "#" %>
    <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
 </footer>
```

Here is the scss file for the app

```
 html,body{
    height: 100%;
 }

 #wrap{
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto -60px;
 }


 .container{
    padding-top: 60px;
 }

 #push, footer{
    height: 60px;

 }

 footer{
margin-top: -60px;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
 }


 @import 'bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

all looks right, but it will be more right if  header  insert  into .wrap block

```
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

   <div class="container">
   <%= yield %>
   </div>
   <div id="push"></div>  
 </div>

 <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

Can you add jsfiddle?